# Point-sampling outside of vector polygons

Tags: polygon, point, sampling

I am using QGIS 3.30.0 to try to sample a defined number of points that are located outside of vector polygons. The overall goal is to have an even number of points within the polygons (positive points if you will) and outside of the polygons (negative points). I can sample the positive points using the "sample points" vector tool which gives me some N number of points based on how I define the distance between points boundaries. I do not know how to sample that same N number of points in areas only outside of the polygons. Ideally, the negative points would have an extent larger than that of the positive points but not infinite. I'm not sure if I could somehow create a single polygon with holes around where the current polygons are and sample that with the "sample points" tool or perhaps there is a better way to accomplish this that I have not considered. I would just like to have a specific number of random points outside of the current polygons.